# App won't build with error Unable to find optional library

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I clean reinstalled Android Studio, as I'm working on a project with some colleagues. We have a successfully buildable, runnable project, which unfortunately does not build on my computer. Freshly cloned from our online repo, it always gives me the following warning and error at build:

> Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy
>   Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

I have no idea how to fix it, as I'm new to Android Developement and it's funny to me that it works on my coulleagues PCs and not on mine.

In the build.gradle (Module: app) file I have the rows

```
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

so I really am curious why the app does not build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found out that I was lacking an *Optional.json* file from the path

AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platforms\android-23\optional

For anyone bumping in the same error, could try checking if the path has the *library*.java files and the *Optional.json* file with all the optional libraries set, like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "org.apache.http.legacy",
    "jar": "org.apache.http.legacy.jar",
    "manifest": false
  }
]
```

Comment: I can't find the AppData folder ?

Comment: Okay I find the folder but there is no 'Android' folder under local folder

Answer (score 1):

well according to Android since API level 23 apache have been deprecated, https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#http, I recommend using Volley. 
http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Edited :

you need to select a different API level i believe that if you'll choose API level 21 it should run easily, in the build.gradle file change the following according to what works for your project.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.answer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

in the lines with the --compileSdkVersion change it to 21
change the ToolsVersion accordingly

and on targetSdkVersion change to 21 aswell.
once done editing Sync the gradle.buid and the recompile.

let me know if that works as I know it should.

Comment: I see what you're trying to tell me, but unfortunately it's not a solution for me. I mean the main problem is that everyone besides me can bulid and run the android project, and all I have is this error. Do I need any addons?

Comment: After your edit: I managed to fix my problem, It was a strange one, but I was lacking the Optional.json file from near the library file from the path AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\platforms\android-23\optional